# For loop assigning last value of list to entire 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

For loop assigning last value of list to entire 2D list.

I have this code:

```
for i in range(len(horiz_lines)):
  for j in range(len(vert_lines)):
    resultant = intersection(horiz_boxes[horiz_lines[i]], vert_boxes[vert_lines[ordered_boxes[j]]])

    for b in range(len(boxes)):
      the_box = [boxes[b][0][0],boxes[b][0][1],boxes[b][2][0],boxes[b][2][1]]
      if iou(resultant,the_box)>0.1:
        out_array[i][j]=texts[b]
        print(out_array[i][j])
```

Now, functions are working fine, when I print out_array inside loop (as given in code), I get expected values. But once I call out_array in next cell and print it, values are changed. What mistake am I making?

Edit:
Here is how out_array was created.

```
out_array = [["" for i in range(len(vert_lines))] for j in range(len(horiz_lines))]
```

Comment: One reason could be that `texts[b]` changed.  You haven't shown us that variable, or how it's used, so we can't know for sure.

Comment: @JohnGordon I checked `texts[b]` by printing, it is what it is supposed to be. Also, it is simple list.

Comment: There are too many unknowns here to say anything with certainty. Having said that — how is `out_array` created? I suspect something similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly).

Comment: @TurePålsson I made edit for out_array. Thanks.

Comment: You're aware that `out_array[i][j]=texts[b]` might be executed many times for the same values of `[i][j]` but different values of `b`?

Comment: What do you mean by "once I call out_array in next cell and print it"?  What do you mean by _call_ exactly?  Do you mean call as in _call a function_? And what do you mean by "next cell"?

Comment: @JohnGordon I am not sure about that. Any way by which I can check this? Btw, `len(horiz_lines)` is 29, `len(vert_lines)` is 5 and `len(texts)` is 55.

Comment: @JohnGordon by next cell, I mean I am running in Jupyter notebook. So after running this loop part, I print out_array in next cell.

Comment: What is a "cell" exactly?  Is it one line of code?

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed us the **exact** output that changed.

Comment: Do you expect `iou(resultant,the_box)>0.1` to be true only once for a given `[i][j]`?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, it should be true only once, also cell is block of code in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Then perhaps the problem is that `iou(resultant,the_box)>0.1` is actually true more than once for a given `[i][j]`.  You can check this yourself by adding a simple print statement inside the if, something like `print(f'out_array[{i}][{j}]=texts[{b}]')` and see if there are two (or more) messages with different values of b for the same values of i and j.

Comment: Or, simpler, just print `i` and `j`, and see if the same values are ever printed twice.

Comment: @JohnGordon i, j for multiple times was case, I changed things in iou function by bit and everything working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`